# Converting an SVG Path to a Base64 data uri string

Tags: image, svg, base64, converters

How would I convert an SVG path to a Base64 data uri string?

Using this svg path as an example. How would I convert it?

```
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1226 1481">
    <path d="M0 1394V87C0 46.3 13.3 19.8 40 7.5 66.7-4.8 98.7.3 136 23l1034 634c37.3 22.7 56 50.3 56 83s-18.7 60.3-56 83L136 1458c-37.3 22.7-69.3 27.8-96 15.5-26.7-12.3-40-38.8-40-79.5z" fill="red"/></svg>
```

Comment: Stick data:image/svg+xml; at the front of it, make sure it has namespaces defined and encode # characters as %23

Comment: I do not understand any of that.

Comment: I guess you need to do some research then. Here's somewhere to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: Your question is missing context. Are you asking for a solution in a certain programming language? Or a command line script? Do you start out with a DOM object, or a string?

Comment: Assuming you want to manually encode the SVG as Base64, then just paste it into an online Base64 encoder. For example [this one](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp). Then copy and paste the encoded text into a Data URI of the correct format. The Wikipedia page Robert linked describes that.